# Remove and return a line of text

Tags: javascript

I have a string with a bunch of text, including new lines. I want a method that removes the next line of text up until the new line, and then returns it.

I know that you can split a string on new lines using the following:

```
 var lines = txt.split('\n');
```

and then you can loop through each index of lines to get each line.

I don't want to split up the entire txt, just remove and return a line from it so that the next time txt is accessed, that last line won't be there anymore.

Essentially, slicing up until a new line is found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use indexOf (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the first `\n` and then substring (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract what comes before.

Comment: Stop supporting w3school, use MDN instead : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring